# "Word Cannot Complete the Save Due to a File Permission Error" when PDF export is triggered

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have .docm documents with VBA code located in

```
Project(Document1)
  |_Microsoft Word Object
    |_ThisDocument
```

The purpose of this code is to export the document as a PDF file when the user saves the file (NOTE : the file already exists in the remote directoy when the user opens it) :

```
Private WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Set App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Word.Documents.Count And ActiveDocument = ThisDocument Then
        Dim strFilename As String
        strFilename = ActiveDocument.Name
        Dim positionPoint As Integer
        positionPoint = InStr(strFilename, ".")
        If positionPoint <> 0 Then
            strFilename = Left(strFilename, positionPoint - 1)
            strPath = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator

            ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat outputFileName:= _
                                            strPath & strFilename & ".pdf", _
                                            ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
                                            OpenAfterExport:=False, _
                                            OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, _
                                            Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
                                            IncludeDocProps:=False, _
                                            CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
                                            BitmapMissingFonts:=True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Most of the times it works just fine but sometimes the user would have a popup say

*Word Cannot Complete the Save Due to a File Permission Error*

If the user retries saving it does not work. Also, the PDF export work, sometimes in under a minute and sometimes it takes a very long time to perform the export, it can take hours. The file is only 300 to 500Ko large. It is saved on a remote directory.

Is there anything I can do in my code to secure the file save ? Is it possible to find another event to trigger the PDF export ? I tried to trigger it before close but it would display a "Do you want to save your file" popup and it is not always relevant to export before close.

Thanks

Comment: This won't solve your problem but - `App_DocumentBeforeSave` has an input parameter, `Doc`, which is the document being saved. You should be using `Doc` in your code, not `ActiveDocument`.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt is it unsafe the way I do it or is it "just" bad code ?

Not exactly on topic but : I added the `ActiveDocument = ThisDocument` condition to prevent the code triggering on every opened .docm file, maybe there is a better way to do this.

Comment: It is possible that when your code runs `ActiveDocument` isn't the same as `Doc`. Good code also tends to be safe code as it is explicit in the use of objects. That is why use of objects such as `ActiveDocument` and `Selection` is considered poor code.

Comment: Is my code located in the right place please ? I will use the event DocumentBeforeClose to try and avoid the save issue but I would like to know if I put the VBA code in the right place.

Comment: Apparently I should use Document_Close() as documents are created from a template and it avoids PDF export to trigger for any opened Word document.